# Is there a memory location that holds the value of NR_syscalls?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am doing a little bit of Linux virtual machine introspection and thus have access to the memory of that particular machine. I would like to know if there is an offset value for NR_syscalls in the kallsyms file (or elsewhere). I ran grep _syscalls but there are a number of values and I'm not sure if one of them is what I'm looking for. My goal is to read all the system call table values from 0 to NR_syscalls so I need to know where the numeric value for NR_syscalls is stored in memory. Note: I do not want to just read from unistd_32.h